# Pivot table in SQL but keep measure names in column

Tags: sql, pivot, unpivot

Im having trouble pivoting a table correct.

My input is this raw data table:

```
+------+---------+------------+----------+
| YEAR | FACULTY | ADMISSIONS | DROPOUTS |
+------+---------+------------+----------+
| 2018 | LAW     |         15 |        2 |
| 2019 | LAW     |         18 |        4 |
| 2020 | LAW     |         11 |        1 |
| 2018 | MATH    |         19 |        1 |
| 2019 | MATH    |         17 |        6 |
| 2020 | MATH    |         24 |        5 |
+------+---------+------------+----------+
```

I want to pivot years to row but I also want to keep the measure for admissions and drop outs as row names. E.g I want a table as this:

```
+---------+------------+------+------+------+
| FACULTY |  MEASURE   | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
+---------+------------+------+------+------+
| LAW     | ADMISSIONS |   15 |   18 |   11 |
| LAW     | DROPOUTS   |    2 |    4 |    1 |
| MATH    | ADMISSIONS |   19 |   17 |   24 |
| MATH    | DROPOUTS   |    1 |    6 |    5 |
+---------+------------+------+------+------+
```

I can pivot years using:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT FACULTY, YEAR, ADMINISSION, DROPPUTS 
        FROM TABLE
        PIVOT (SUM (ADMISSIONS) 
        FOR YEAR IN (2018,2019,2020)
    )
```

But I need to pivot both measures and still get the measure names column. Any ideas?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

That's unpivoting, then pivoting. If your database supports lateral joins and `values()`, you can do:

```
select
    t.faculty,
    x.measure,
    sum(case when t.year = 2018 then x.value end) value_2018,
    sum(case when t.year = 2019 then x.value end) value_2019,
    sum(case when t.year = 2020 then x.value end) value_2020
from mytable t
cross apply (values ('admission', admission), ('dropout', dropout)) as x(measure, value)
group by t.faculty, x.measure
```

Answer (score 0):

I would unpivot using `apply` (assuming you are using SQL Server) and reaggregate:

```
select t.faculty, v.measure,
       max(case when year = 2018 then val end) as [2018],
       max(case when year = 2019 then val end) as [2019],
       max(case when year = 2020 then val end) as [2020]
from t cross apply
     (values ('ADMISSIONS', ADMISSIONS), ('DROPOUTS', DROPOUTS)
     ) v(measure, val)
group by t.faculty, v.measure
```